# Struts2 autocomplete form submission with only the suggested values

Tags: autocomplete, struts2

I am using struts2 autocomplete in a form. I will do a form submit after I choose all fields through autocomplete on various text boxes. Now, I don't want to allow user to type a random input in the auto complete text box and allow a submit. How to tackle this ?

**EDIT:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="createproduct" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="density" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select
                    Density</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <sj:autocompleter size="30" list="descArray" name="desc"
                        id="density" placeholder="Density" class="form-control"></sj:autocompleter>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="density" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select
                    Material</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <sj:autocompleter size="30" list="matArray" name="mat" id="mat"
                        placeholder="Material" class="form-control"></sj:autocompleter>
                </div>
            </div>
..... //// more form elements go here ...... /////
```

Comment: It depends on the autocompleter you use. Show some code. BTW S2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Comment: I have added some code to show you what is going. If dojo plugins are recommended, can you please suggest me the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) jquery plugin.You can either fetch all the details and initialize the plugin or can fetch info on demand.

Fetching info based on input;

```
 $("#material").select2({
                 tags: false,
                 minimumInputLength: 1, // Minimum Input length for search request
                 ajax: {
                     url:'actionName',
                     dataType:'json',
                     data:function(params){
                         return{
                             materialSearchTerm: params.term, // search term
                             page: params.page
                         };
                     },
                      processResults: function (data, page) {
                          var jsonResult = JSON.parse(data);
                          return {
                              results: jsonResult.result
                          };
                      }

                 }
            });
```

actionName should return select input as JSON.

eg;- `{result:[{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];}`